# Polynomial Constrained Least Squares curve fitting with matlab

Tags: matlab, constraints, curve-fitting, polynomial-math

I want to fit and draw a curve that is constrained with the following boundary condition:

```
diff (yfit)<=0
```

where `yfit` is the polynomial fitted function to degree `n`.

The condition ensures that the slope of the polynomial to any degree of is non-positive for all `x` .

How can I apply the condition using the "`polyfit`" function or any other polynomial fitting function?

Answer (score 0):

From my limited point of mathematical view, a polynomial function of degree 2 for example has by definition a reagion with positive and negative slope. 
One thing you can try is using absolute values:
Build your own fitting (ie least square is easy = polyfit) and dont use polynomial
Functions, but absolute functions thereof.

Least sqare: take 0 = d/da ( sum( func-point)^2 ) and this for each order.. Wikipedia and others provide in depth descriptions.